# Truncating partition locking whole table in mysql

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

Novice here. I have a huge data that is generated every day and are stored in day wise partition. However, I have a cron that automatically deletes the old day (30 days ago). The query for deletion is as follows:

ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PARTITION p20210206;
The doc of mysql(5.7) [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html) says when we drop a partition of innodb tables then the other partition does not get locked. However, when I perform any query during this process of partition deletion, they get locked.

I hit a small insert query and this is the status in FULL PROCESS LIST

```
    id: 32031012
   User: ab
   Host: myhost
     db: myDB
Command: Query
   Time: 1
  State: Waiting for table metadata lock
   Info: INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (9, 1, NULL, NULL, 'SUCCESS', '2020-02-05 09:46:13.356', '2020-02-05 09:47:36.869', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 20210307)
Can someone, please explain me why are the other partition getting locked and how can I overcome this problem.
```

Also, if the truncation query fails due to any reason, will the lock continue or will it be freed?

Comment: Is this cross-posted?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked explicitly refers to `alter table ... truncate partition ...` statement, not to the `alter table ... drop partition ...` you use according to the question that only locks the partition being purged.

Furthermore, the linked manual says that

> In addition, ALTER TABLE statements take metadata locks on the table level.

The error message you received is in line with the documented behaviour.

You probably need to perform the drop operation while your system is not used to avoid this locking issue.